# How to solve Error 000840 from arcpy.JoinField_management?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, excel, error-000840

As part of a larger Python script, I am attempting for my last step to join an Excel file to a spatial layer.  I was able to perform this step just fine in ArcGIS Pro Model Builder, but when I attempt to do it with a stand-alone script in Python I get an error (below).

I imported pandas and arcpy at the beginning.  I set the workspace to 'G:\Project.'  Then there are intervening steps with the Excel file that all ran just fine.  But here is the problematic script.

```
# Join new Excel file to spatial layer  
inFeatures = r'G:\Project\spatiallayer.lyrx'  
joinTable = r'G:\Project\Excel.xlsx'  
joinField = "OBJECTID"

joined_table = arcpy.JoinField_management(inFeatures, joinField, joinTable, joinField)
```

And here is the error I get:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.  
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Table View.  
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.  
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.  
Failed to execute (JoinField).
```

I originally had a layer package, but Python would not recognize that, so I created a new layer from that package.  And the error above is what I get when I attempt the Join Field with that new layer.  What makes this so baffling is that it works in ModelBuilder using the same inputs.  I don't understand why it will not accept my layer to join with my Excel file.  How can I solve this error?

I am running Python 3.6.1 and ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1.

Comment: I haven't tried to do this with either a layer file, or excel file - but my guess is you need to use MakeTableView first, and pass the result of that to the joinField.  See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-table-view.htm

Comment: Perhaps review our [self-assembling FAQ on ERROR 000840](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000840?tab=Frequent).  Have you tried converting your Excel table to a geodatabase table and joining that instead?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the sheet name `joinTable = r'G:\Project\Excel.xlsx\Somesheet1$' `

Comment: Hi BERA, I tried your suggestion of specifying the sheet name, and now the JoinField script runs successfully! I kept thinking, based on the error code and description, that it was an issue with the layer file.  But it was actually with how I was specifying the Excel file, so your solution worked!  Thank you!